# In Django, how can make an inline field editable only if it is null or empty?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I currently have a tabular inline that has an `end_date` field for a model.
I want the field to only be editable if it is empty or null, and read only otherwise.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Currently, I have it editable regardless, but I want the data that already exists to be read only. Here is the code:

```py
class DeploymentInline(DecoratedTabularInline):
    model = Deployment
    readonly_fields = ['updated_at', 'updated_by', 'start_date', 'tool']
    fields = ['tool', 'updated_at', 'updated_by', 'start_date', 'end_date', ]

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj):
        return False
```

I tried using `get_readonly_field` and checking the `obj` parameter, but it refers to the `Project` which is the `admin.ModelAdmin` the inline is in.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872386/how-to-override-or-hide-django-admin-model-form-field-value
i search answer for your question hope so it will work 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72872386/how-to-override-or-hide-django-admin-model-form-field-value

Answer (score 1):

You can add override the form of the InlineAdmin Form, like this:

```
class DeploymentAdminForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Deployment

    def __init__(self, instance=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(instance=instance, **kwargs)
        if instance and instance.end_date:
            self.fields['end_date'].disabled = True

class DeploymentInline(DecoratedTabularInline):
    form = DeploymentAdminForm
```

More information can be found in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form).